# Reading "nested" request (with points as delimiter)

Tags: node.js, express

I'm sending the following HTTP Post parameter (in the body of HTTP):

`pickupAddress.city=MyTown`

I expected to read it like this:

`req.body.pickupAddress` should be a JavaScript object:

```
var pickupAddress = req.body.pickupAddress;
var pickupAddressCity = pickupAddress.city;
```

Unfortunately this is not working as `pickupAddress.city` in the request seems to be a string (console output is `'pickupAddress.city'`).

How can this be done?

Comment: `req.body['pickupAddress.city']`, though I'd recommend fixing how you send your parameter.

Comment: How would you send it? Problem is that I send two addresses (1 pickup and 1 handover address).

Comment: AFAIK if you use `pickupAddress[city]=MyTown` then body-parser will pick it up.

Comment: Just tried that. Doesn't work.

Comment: Are you passing `extended: true` along with `bodyParser.urlencoded`?

Comment: You were right. Extended was false. Now it's working! :-)